# "-style" and "-like" in compound adjectives

Tags: adjectives, compounds

To describe something that looks similar to something else, English provides us *style* and *like* words to create compound adjectives. For example:

> - Elvis–Presley-style dance
> - Elvis–Presley-like dance

Or:

> - bell-like
> - bell-style

(meaning: 1. having or producing a clear musical sound like that of a bell. "her clear bell-like voice" 2. shaped like a bell. "bell-like flowers")

But how we can know in which cases to use "-style" and in which cases to use "-like"?

Comment: You don't. As with all compounds, the individual parts are not predictable. Some will go together, and some won't; and some have been together for so long that you can't tell the parts.

Comment: Do you know the meanings of the preposition "like" and the noun "style"? Their meanings in combination are similar to their meanings otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Style" implies a a pattern people have chosen and imitate. It makes sense to say "Presley-style dance," or "bell-bottom-style trousers," or "SUV-style (or *styled*) vehicle."

For a natural object, one is less likely to use "style". "Bell-like flower," or "pearl-like teeth," would be used.

**Caveats:**

- A [*style*](https://www.britannica.com/science/style-plant-anatomy) is part of a flower, part of the pistil.
- A common phrase is, "I like your style," meaning, "I like the way you present yourself (dress, hair-*style*...).

Comment: Thanks, now it is much clearer to me.